# How can I (exp)-transform my y-axis in Spline Curve using the rms-package in R?

Tags: r, regression, cubic-spline

I have produced a Restricted Cubic Spline curve using the rms-package. You can see the plot below:

[image]

I wish to transform the `log Relative Hazard`-y axis to just `Relative Hazard`.

I used the following script and my data can be found below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rms)

d <- datadist(w)
options(datadist="d")
model=cph(Surv(Follow.up.death,Death)~rcs(total.mbq),data=w)
ggplot(Predict(model),fun=function(x){exp(x)})
```

My data:

```
w <- structure(list(Follow.up.death = c(18, 2, 14, 17, 31, 4, 20, 
                                   15, 12, 19, 10, 17, 27, 22, 3, 43, 24, 14, 13, 5, 12, 137, 22, 
                                   87, 48, 24, 72, 32, 14, 83, 68, 56, 57, 18, 16, 70, 1.9, 69.2, 
                                   126.3, 41.6, 17.9, 1.3, 87.4, 4.4, 137.4, 17.5, 95.8, 65.2, 14.8, 
                                   98.5, 16.6, 74.9, 10.3, 43.4, 32.5, 4.8, 7.3, 107.8, 6.8, 18.3, 
                                   33, 25.2, 49.2, 15.9, 1.2, 42.7, 1, 9, 1.8, 15.6, 8.9, 15, 16.4, 
                                   7.7, 75.5, 12.2, 54.8, 22.2, 9.7, 14.3, 5.2, 64.5, 21.8, 0.2, 
                                   7.3, 18.7, 5.1, 17.3, 27.4, 16, 24.2, 9.7, 8.2, 5.7, 41.8, 10.6, 
                                   22.8, 4.8, 6, 4, 50, 21, 30, 5, 11, 12), Death = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                      0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                      0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                                                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                      1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), total.mbq = c(29354L, 7445L, 22309L, 
                                                                                                                                 29699L, 29711L, 14765L, 22257L, 29715L, 29772L, 13320L, 20905L, 
                                                                                                                                 12950L, 3400L, 14800L, 7400L, 21890L, 19400L, 14800L, 14700L, 
                                                                                                                                 22200L, 1688L, 4500L, 8438L, 13500L, 14800L, 12580L, 12950L, 
                                                                                                                                 13320L, 11840L, 13320L, 14800L, 13690L, 11250L, 12210L, 13320L, 
                                                                                                                                 13320L, 14800L, 12580L, 20720L, 11840L, 14800L, 7030L, 14800L, 
                                                                                                                                 14800L, 8325L, 11100L, 10730L, 13690L, 12210L, 14800L, 13320L, 
                                                                                                                                 14800L, 12950L, 22200L, 17945L, 22200L, 8140L, 13690L, 11581L, 
                                                                                                                                 14430L, 13320L, 13320L, 21090L, 11100L, 3885L, 6475L, 6660L, 
                                                                                                                                 6660L, 5920L, 7500L, 5000L, 12500L, 12500L, 10000L, 12500L, 7500L, 
                                                                                                                                 15000L, 10000L, 5000L, 7500L, 5000L, 15000L, 12500L, 7500L, 7500L, 
                                                                                                                                 7500L, 5000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 12500L, 5000L, 5000L, 10000L, 
                                                                                                                                 12500L, 5000L, 10000L, 10000L, 22200L, 14800L, 29000L, 14000L, 
                                                                                                                                 4800L, 21600L, 28800L, 11400L)), .Names = c("Follow.up.death", 
                                                                                                                                                                             "Death", "total.mbq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -106L))
```

Comment: I suggest viewing the data as a 3D scatterplot.

Comment: @JamesPhillips thank you for your comment. Could you provide an example? And can you help me if I want to show data as described above?

Comment: There is an even easier way. Make a 2D scatterplot of follow_up_death versus mbq, and since Death has values of 1 or 0 then use different colors for those values - say, Death=0 is blue and Death=1 is red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by changing

```
ggplot(Predict(model),fun=function(x){exp(x)})
```

to

```
ggplot(Predict(model,fun=exp))
```